# Why does image-url with data() have a problem in vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

[enter image description here][1]

In template tag, image-url is working. but In vue script tag, image-url is not working. what is static/ and what can I do to solve this problem? Please refer to the image below
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qa5aH.jpg

Comment: And please next time add your code or link to your code from sandbox, fiddle, codepen or anyhow.. Because screenshots cannot help you in all cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this way..

```
image: require('./img/2.jpg')
```